# Matlab pcolor() function and mirror output

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot an image of a matrix using the pcolor(). The matrix presents a field. (In my case a sea field! But it does not matter:) ). The problem is that when I plot the matrix using pcolor() the matrix is ploted mirrored.

An example:

A=[1 0 0;0 1 0;0 0 1];

If I plot the matrix, the cell (0,0) will be plotted not in the top left corner but in the bottom left corner.(Its obvious the start of the axes is (0,0) I understand that the function is working properly!) I know also the existence of the flipdim() functions to flip the matrix.
The problem is that the code becomes ugly if I use this approach.For example the cell(0,0) in the matrix will be appeared in cell(size(A,1),0) and everything becomes opposite! How can I face that problem in a more elegant way?
(The matrix to be printed as a terian for example and not mirrored)

Edit:

Solved using axis ij

Comment: Not too sure if I fully follow your problem correctly. But if I do, pcolor does plot matrices in an uncommon way IMO. Does pcolor(A.') fix your issue?

Comment: if I plot pcolor(eye(5)); I receive the opposite image((Mirrored). Am I right on that ? I want to have 1 on the top left and not 1 on the bottom left of the plot

Comment: I think I fixed it using axis ij. Thanks for the help!Goodnight!

Comment: @nikosdi: You should make you last comment as your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to change the direction of axis you can set `YDir` (or `XDir`) property from normal to reverse.

```
set(gca,'YDir','rev')
```

PCOLOR function produce axis with `YDir` set to normal. In opposite, IMAGESC's `YDir` is reverse by default.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Better answer than what I found, as it can be applied generally.